# SQL Server 2012 Express 32 bits or SQL Server 2014 Express 64 bits

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a machine with Visual Studio (Windows 8.1 64 bits). I use Entity Framework with a SQL Server 2012 Express 32 bits.

I just created a server of test (Windows 7 pro 64 bits)

I ask me if I can put new version of SQL Server 2014 Express 64 bits? Or is it better to put same version as my computer?

If I use 2014 version, when I put my publish Web Site, what arrive? Is there risk of not connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I make an Image of my disk (True Image) install SQL Express 2014 and try ...
Goog no need to change one thing. Run directly .